# Rails 3 - A better way... i'm a newbie!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please, can you suggest me a better way to accomplish this:

```
@infos = @activity.infos
@infos.each do |info|
  @activity.name = info.title if info.language_id == 1
end
```

**EDIT**

In my Rails app contents can be inserted in many languages, but are displayed only in one of them. Other languages are used only as XML output.
However the main cause i'm using this approach is that without a "name" attribute i wouldn't be able to create a collection like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:event, :activity_id, @activities, :id, :name) %>
```

Can you suggest me how to accomplish this without a "name" attribute in my Activity?

Thanks!

Comment: Logically that looks weird.  You're setting the name of the activity based on the language_id of the last info associated with the activity?  Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean logically better! My way was clearly absurd ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
info = @activity.infos.select{|info| info.language_id == 1}.last
@activity.name = info.title
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as the others but using the ARrel syntax that's available in rails 3.

```
@activity.name = @activity.infos.where(:language_id => 1).first.title
```

As the others mentioned ... you might want rethink your design.  If you provide more detail on why you are trying to do this we may be able to help with the underlying design that lead to this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could lose the iteration...

```
@activity.name = @activity.infos.find(:first, :conditions => { :language_id => 1 }).title
```

but that doesn't guarantee you'll get a result (in the real world).  So:

```
info = @activity.infos.find(:first, :conditions => { :language_id => 1 })
@activity.name = info.title unless info.nil?
```

But as mentioned in the comments this is a strange approach - seems like there's something structurally wrong with your app/data if you're trying to assign a value this way.